# A Request for Clarification on Quiver Reps and Gabriel's Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, representation-theory, quiver

I've turned myself around thinking about indecomposable representations of quivers and Gabriel's Theorem and I would be grateful if someone could point out my misunderstanding.

> Suppose you have a $D_4$-like quiver $Q$ with nodes $Q_0 = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and arrows 
>   \begin{equation*}
> Q_1 = \left\{ 1\xrightarrow{a}4 \quad 4\xrightarrow{b}2 \quad 4\xrightarrow{c}3 \right\}\,.
> \end{equation*}
>   Let $X$ be the representation of $Q$ where $\dim X_1 = \dim X_2 = \dim X_3 = 1$ and $\dim X_4 = 2$ and, picking a basis at each node, let $X_a = \binom 1 0 $ is the inclusion into the first component, $X_b = (0\,1)$ the projection onto the second component, and $X_c = (1\,1)$. This representation is indecomposable, and by Gabriel's theorem is the unique indecomposable representation with this dimension vector up to isomorphism. But what about the representation $X'$ that is the same as $X$ except we swap the maps $X_b$ and $X_c$? That is $X'_b = (1\,1)$ and $X'_c = (0\,1)$? By symmetry $X'$ will also be indecomposable, but noting that $X_bX_a = 0$ while $X'_aX'_b \neq 0$, these representations are not isomorphic and are not the same up to a change of basis at the nodes.

Where is my misunderstanding here? Is there some "Up to *some equivalence*" I've overlooked?

Comment: I don't know much about this, but is "by Gabriel's theorem is the unique indecomposable representation with this dimension vector up to isomorphism" something special to the $D_4$-diagram ?

Comment: @Max Nope. [Gabriel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel's_theorem) says that a quiver of shape $D_4$ will have finitely many indecomposable representations (up to isomorphism) since it's a Dynkin diagram, and those indecomposables are in bijective correspondence with the positive roots of the root system for $D_4$. So this is the *unique* indecomposable for the highest root.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant specifically the part about uniqueness (which you answered by mentioning the highest root, so it's all fine :-) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The representation $X$ that you describe is not indecomposable.

This becomes clear if you write $X_4$ as the direct sum of the image of $X_a$ and the kernel of $X_c$.